# Design pattern for implementing plugins in PHP applications

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, plugins, observer-pattern

Is there a consensus on how plugins should be implemented in a PHP application?

I've looked into the [observer pattern](http://devzone.zend.com/1732/implementing-the-observer-pattern-with-splobserver-and-splsubject/) which comes close, it's really just a notification system and doesn't allow code to extend the application directly. I'm currently using a simple hook systems that I came up with:

```
public function registerHook($hookName, array $params = array())
{
    $this->hooks[] = $hookName;

    foreach ( $this->plugins as $pluginName => $hooks ) {
        if ( in_array($hookName, $hooks) ) {
            $plugin = new $pluginName($this, $this->view, $this->controller);

            $plugin->{$hookName}($params);
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for my purposes but I'm curious if there's a design pattern out there that has been tested and proven many times over and I'm just re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at how it works with Wordpress. I don't know myself, but I have a feeling it's using hooks, and BOY does wordpress have a ton of plugins. Good question, upvoted.

Comment: @Relequestual I'm familiar with WordPress, they take a procedural approach with "actions". http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: I'm going to say this question is not a dupe, but in some way it sort of is. Seems the consensus was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42/best-way-to-allow-plugins-for-a-php-application

Comment: I read that but it's an old thread. PHP 5.3 has many OO features that can be leveraged.

Comment: With the observer pattern, you can/need to activate observers at the point where you want to be able to extend your code. I.e. you need to have designated trigger points at which you hit up your observers and have them tell you if there is anything else that you need to do. Definitely not the cleanst way of drop-in-code-have-it-do-the-rest.

Comment: How about subclassing an abstract `plugin` class, or maybe an interface, that contains a number of methods (the hooks) that can be implemented/overloaded by a plugin (eg. enable, disable, on_certain_action)? An autoloader could handle the instantiation. Interesting question indeed.

Comment: @fuzzyDunlop That's almost exactly what I did, e.g. https://github.com/ElbertF/Swiftlet/blob/master/Swiftlet/Plugin.php and https://github.com/ElbertF/Swiftlet/blob/master/Swiftlet/Plugins/Example.php.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong , but doesnt every good framework have a hooking system ? Are you using a framework? If not , maybe take a look at Code igniter core files and see how the hooking system works there. Simply allow and run some process in a key point in your system , thats how i see this implementation of plugins , i don't think theres a pattern

Comment: @TudorTudor Not using a framework but creating one (yes, ironic for someone who doesn't want to reinvent the wheel.) It seems that every framework out there has it's own way of implementing plugins.

Comment: @ElbertF it's good that your makning your own framework , i made mine also , and inspired mostly on CI . Most of the PHP frameworks have flaws , and maybe you can better them . For me CI hooking system it's easy to read and understand . Idk how zend's hooking system is because it's a hell to look at theyr core files

Comment: You might be interested on [these design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913898/4970442)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no consensus as in the Silver Bullet sense. For established patterns, you have multiple options like

- [Subject](http://php.net/splsubject)/[Observer](http://php.net/splobserver),
- [Signal Slot](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/SignalSlot),
- [Event Dispatcher](http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/) or
- [Pipes and Filters](http://eaipatterns.com/PipesAndFilters.html)

to name a few.

Which you use is up to you, but you should make sure your system architecture supports the modularity. Have a look at these slides for some ideas

- http://qafoo.com/talks/11_06_ipc_spring_modular_application_architecture.pdf

Comment: @Gordon What do you think about decorating the main 'application' object (like silex has), doing your modifications to it, then returning it? Then you could repeatedly decorate these, adding more decorators for each new application modification, and being able to remove each one any time without affecting the rest?

Comment: @Jimbo Sure, if that's what you want to do. But keep in mind that a Decorator usually only operates on the existing API of the decorated class. You could also use [Silex `before()` and `after()` hooks](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html).

Answer (score 3):

I think an Events Dispatcher is a nice and clean way to implement plugins, or any extension for that matter. An Events Dispatcher is an implementation of the Observer pattern, and is being used in symfony, [Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) and [Zend Framework 2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) (beta).

Looking through any of that source on github will make for some interesting reading. Though, an interesting bit of information can be found here:

http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/trunk/book/02-Recipes

I wrote an Events and Hooks class a few years back for a project, I'll post that here if I can find it.

Comment: I suppose you never found it :)

Comment: Yeah, he never found it :-)

Comment: Nope, never found it. :)

Comment: Please find it... :)

Comment: It's been 4 years OP. Did you ever find it?

Comment: The event dispatcher is the best solution that comes to mind. because in php if you pass an object as parameter, you can set its properties and call its methods. (after return, the app can act on the event, by looking at the object properties. e.g. its new state)

Comment: It's 2017. Was this ever found?

Comment: Search still in progress.

Comment: You are so lazy sir, you may need centuries but Alas life is short!

Comment: Can I help with the search?

Comment: @ericek111 Definitely! Do you have proven experience finding things that never existed? Alas, search still in progress...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Yii framework.  Yii heavily relies on events which are much cleaner than hooks, actions, etc.  Using events, you can allow different parts of the system to talk to each other in an object oriented manner.

Comment: I'm not really looking for code examples but I'll have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework is using the dispatchLoopStartup() and dispatchLoopShutdown() hooks as class methods.
Each plugin is a class that implements the aforementioned methods.

[ZF manual reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins)

Answer (score 1):

The way you've done this, with hooks is also how I implement this.

The biggest problem with your sample though, is that your function instantiates the plugin. Why not pass an instance of the plugin instead?

The way I've done this, is that a plugin gets instantiated first, and registers its hooks itself.

Comment: A plugin may implement several hooks, creating a new instance for each avoids a shared state.

Comment: The shared state is something the plugin itself should be aware of. If you need separate states, use multiple objects.

Comment: Why is it an issue though? It keeps the hook implementations separated and there's no need to keep track of plugin instances.

Comment: You loose a lot of functionality that OOP gives. By doing this, you're effectively treating your objects as static. If you want to read more about this, look for 'Dependency injection'. Just general design patterns will also be of benefit. Even though this may not seem as an issue now, in the future I guarantee you'll see this is inflexible..

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a link to the project called [jin-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jin-plugin/) right in the [Wikipedia article about Plugin concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29). I am seeing this framework first time, too, but, maybe, you can use it right away.

Besides, you should really google for things like "Plugin Pattern", there's just two links I found on first page: [Plug-in Pattern](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/PlugInPattern.html), [Extensibility pattern (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility_pattern).

If it's really a pattern, it should be language agnostic, so you can safely take any existing solution from any language and convert it to PHP.

P. S. Thanks for question, anyway, you really did raise my own interest in this topic. ;)